# ExtJs Layout: Can't display Ext.form.Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, layout, extjs4, formpanel

Hello im trying to display my Filter Panel but it doenst work anybody an idea why? im tryed to set my window.js to layout: 'border' but without success i found some examples @ sencha but im failed [sencha layouts](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html)

My window.js

```
Ext.define('Shopware.apps.UnSqlReader.view.window.Window', {
extend: 'Enlight.app.Window',
alias: 'widget.main-window-view',
height: '90%',
width: '90%',
layout: 'fit',
title: '{s name=window_title}SQL Reader{/s}',
minimizable: true,
maximizable: true,
menuDisabled: true,
enableCtxMenu: false,
initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;
    me.items = me.getItems();
    me.callParent(arguments);
},
getItems: function() {
    var me = this;
    me.filterGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        height: '90%',
        width: '90%',
        autoScroll: true,
        hidden: true,
        cls: 'enable-scroll-bar',
        layout: 'border',
        split: true,
        overflowX: 'scroll',
        overflowY: 'scroll',
        items: [
        Ext.create('Shopware.apps.UnSqlReader.view.filter.Filter', {
            region: 'west'
        })],
        columns: [],
    });
    return [me.filterGrid, me.grid];
},
```

My filter.js

```
Ext.define('Shopware.apps.UnSqlReader.view.filter.Filter', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
title: 'Filter',
collapsible: true,
width: 300,
layout: 'anchor',
region: 'west',
initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;
    console.log('Filter Loaded');
    me.items = [
    me.createFilterButton(),
    me.createResetButton()],
    me.callParent();
},
createFilterButton: function() {
    var me = this;
    me.filterButton = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
        cls: 'secondary small',
        width: 130,
        iconCls: 'sprite-funnel',
        text: 'Set Filter',
        handler: function() {

        }
    });
    return me.filterButton;
},
createResetButton: function() {
    var me = this;
    me.resetButton = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
        cls: 'secondary small',
        width: 130,
        iconCls: 'sprite-funnel--minus',
        text: 'Reset Filter',
        handler: function() {}
    });
    return me.resetButton;
}
```

[image: Grid View]

Comment: Can you send a dummy expected result screenshot  (through paint) to here.  and also post complete code. I can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having trouble getting a Panel to show over my existing single page application. I found that using an [Ext.window.Window](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.window.Window) as a container for my popup dialog was really what I wanted.  It displayed just fine:

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title: 'Hello',
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: {  // Let's put an empty grid in just to illustrate fit layout
        xtype: 'grid',
        border: false,
        columns: [{header: 'World'}],                 // One header just for show. There's no data,
        store: Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {}) // A dummy empty data store
    }
}).show();
```

Answer (score 3):

Any Container using the Border layout must have a child item with region:'center'. The child item in the center region will always be resized to fill the remaining space not used by the other regions in the layout.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Border